# Getting started with game development using js/html5

Tags: javascript, html

Anyone have experience with game development using javascript and the html5 canvas element?

So far I have found two libraries, are either of these worth using?

http://tommysmind.com/ (XNA Port)

http://gamequery.onaluf.org/ (jquery plugin)

Does anyone have any other resources?

Comment: With the increasing support of html5 and the decreasing support of flash (iPad, iPhone) it looks like there is a lot of opportunity for js/html5 gaming.

Comment: What type of games are you thinking of?

Comment: Basic 2d games. Puzzle, side scroller type things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use Lime JS - very promising HTML5 game developement framework. 
http://www.limejs.com

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to this ;-) but here are some current or emerging frameworks

Aves http://www.dextrose.com/en/projects/aves-engine
Akihabara http://www.kesiev.com/akihabara/ 
Rokcet Pack http://rocketpack.fi/
Effect Games http://www.effectgames.com/effect/

these are probably overkill for the kind of games you're mostly referring to.

Also, take a look at Sencha Touch

http://www.sencha.com/

There's a very slick solataire example here

http://touchsolitaire.mobi/app/

HTH

Answer (score 2):

impact js looks really cool, http://impactjs.com/ but it has $99 price tag :( But it comes with an awesome level editor so it might be worth the price.

Answer (score 2):

For basic 2d games i would use either impact or [Crafty](http://craftyjs.com)
Crafty is open source, but impact has a cool level editor.

All the others that i have tested are either lacking in some areas or too expensive. Aves and Rocket has been bought by Zynga and Disney.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Processing.js](http://processingjs.org/). Maybe you can use it for 2D drawing and user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use for example this one port http://cocos2d-javascript.org/ for game dev.

Answer (score 1):

Another library you could look at is [google forplay](http://code.google.com/p/forplay/). While not a true javascript/html5 library it compiles to javascript from java much in a way like GWT.

Answer (score 1):

I have not built a game engine but rather a classic game in its near-entirety, plus a few simple animations, into [my Tetris clone](http://htmltetris.com).

Its most important feature in my opinion is the effectiveness of the multitouch control scheme when you load up the page in iOS or Android. The idea is for it to be intuitive enough that I shouldn't have to show instructions for the user to figure out how to play it.

Comment: Your game also pauses when you want to drop something (because the pause button also captures the focus?). Other than that nice job!

Comment: What, when you press spacebar? Are you on desktop or mobile?

Comment: Yes, when you press space bar. I am not sure but I think I was using Chrome on Windows. I am trying now again with Chromium on Ubuntu, but no issue there.

Comment: Hm. I'll try that when I get home...

Comment: For posterity's sake: This link was dead for years, but now it's not anymore. I didn't renew the htmltetris.com domain since the tetris company was threatening to sue me, and now it seems like the site has been revived, someone put some spam links in the HTML but the core game is still intact. Thanks for the free hosting...

Answer (score 0):

Try our HTML5 game engine, [Construct 2](http://www.scirra.com) (http://www.scirra.com).  We have an extensive free edition available so you can play around with it!

It's an event based system which means you don't need to know programming to get going in it.  However it is extendable with our Javascript SDK so anyone can write their own plugins to extend it's functionality.

A few great games have started to pop up on our arcade now as proof that it works well!
http://www.scirra.com/arcade

Comment: Hi,  is there a construct2 version for linux.  I was happy to find it till I discovered it's just for windows.

Comment: Sorry, Windows only at the moment :(  Although some users run it in a VM like Parallels on Mac, not sure about Linux though I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I have personal experience of developing a HTML 5 browser game with [Dead Earth](http://dead-earth.com)! I found that I did not need to use any specific libaries other than JQuery along with a few Jquery plugins.

I used the Canvas and the Audio elements in Dead Earth. But I did not create any fancy 3D graphics I only drew shapes and images, colouring said shapes, drew lines etc.

I imagine if you are doing something more complicated than this you may need a library otherwise why make your app more bloated than it needs to be?